# Ember-Template-Lint How to fix block-indentation errors on hbs files?

Tags: javascript, npm, ember.js, handlebars.js, eslint

I am able to run eslint on *.js files. However, it does not seem to support handlebar files.

I did some searching online and found Ember-Template-Lint. But, I am unable to figure out how to change automatically fix block indentations. Is it possible to automatically fix all block indentation errors on Ember handle bar files?

1.) What rule do I use in .template-lintrc.js (see code below)?

2.) What command do I run from the terminal to fix any/all *.hbs files?

https://github.com/ember-template-lint/ember-template-lint

**.template-lintrc.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    extends: 'recommended',

    rules: {
        'no-html-comments': false,
        'no-bare-strings': false
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember Template Lint does not support fixing errors automatically yet. But it's under active development. You can track progress in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ember-template-lint/ember-template-lint/issues/1180).

You can use [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) for Glimmer Templates to automatically format your code. This will fix indentation related template linting errors. But the Glimmer support for Prettier is still experimental. It's tracked in [this quest issue at GitHub](https://github.com/jgwhite/prettier/issues/1).

If using Prettier for Glimmer Templates I would recommend to integrate Prettier with Ember Template Lint through [`ember-template-lint-plugin-prettier`](https://github.com/ember-template-lint/ember-template-lint-plugin-prettier).

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime, are there any other tools that can do handlebar linting?

Comment: @JWeezy There isn't any another tool that can lint Glimmer templates as far as I know. I'm not sure about Handlebar templates but as syntax used in Ember/Glimmer templates have changed from orginal Handlebars a lot I'm not sure if that would work out at all. But I added Prettier as an alternative option. But also the Ember/Glimmer language support for Prettier is still experimental. I guess it needs a little bit more time until both options are stable.